# Pyspark date intervals and between dates?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In Snowflake/SQL we can do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTbl 
WHERE date_col 
BETWEEN 
  CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','America/Los_Angeles', some_date_string_col)::DATE - INTERVAL '7 DAY'
AND 
  CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','America/Los_Angeles', some_date_string_col)::DATE - INTERVAL '1 DAY'
```

Is there a pyspark translation for this for **dataframes?**

I imagine if something like this

```py
myDf.filter(
  col(date_col) >= to_utc_timestamp(...)
)
```

But how can we do `BETWEEN` and also the `interval`?

Comment: Here's an explanation for between: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403903/pysparks-between-function-range-search-on-timestamps-is-not-inclusive

Comment: @MattAndruff what about `interval`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INTERVAL` within SQL expression like this:

```py
df1 = df.filter(
        F.col("date_col").between(
            F.expr("current_timestamp - interval 7 days"),
            F.expr("current_timestamp - interval 1 days"),
        )
    )
```

---

However if you only filter using days, you can simply use `date_add` (or `date_sub`) function:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.filter(
    F.col("date_col").between(
        F.date_add(F.current_date(), -7),
        F.date_add(F.current_date(), -1)
    )
)
```